# Rails: Populating a triple join table with select boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select, join

I have a domain model which includes a triple join very similar to this: [Triple join in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636296/triple-join-in-ruby-on-rails)

I have implemented the models as suggested by the accepted answer, however I'm struggling to implement a form for populating the groups table.

My form needs to provide a way to assign multiple memberships to the group. The design I am working with achieves this with sets of two select boxes, one for a user and one for a role. I have tried adding multiple sets of select boxes with code similar to this:

```
<%= select 'group','users', User.all.collect {|u| [u.display_name, u.id]} %>
<%= select 'group', 'roles', Role.all.collect {|r| [r.name, r.id]} %>
<br />    
<%= select 'group','users', User.all.collect {|u| [u.display_name, u.id]} %>
<%= select 'group', 'roles', Role.all.collect {|r| [r.name, r.id]} %>
```

However, Rails only passes the values from the last set of selects into the controller. Is there a way to create multiple instances of a join table inside a single form with multiple selects? What would the create action look like for such a form?

Comment: First off, it's the nature of html that only sends one value for a given field to the server on form submit, not a Rails thing. The question I have here is that it is not clear what you are trying to do with this form. Are you trying to add multiple users to multiple groups or a single user to multiple groups or multiple users to a single group? What you have now seems set to put one user in one group and a second user in a second group. It seems like you should be using :multiple => true on one side or the other.

Comment: A "membership" in my model is a user with a role who belongs to a group. ie. The each row of the join table relates to one row in three other tables. In the form, I want to create multiple rows in the join table using only one submit.